# access service variable in routing file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How can I get my service variable in routing file.

I made a `UserService` which has a variable `user` and I want to access that variable in my routing file.

Below is my approach which didn't work:

In routing file, I wrote:

```
const steps = userService.user.onboardingStatus;   //shows error ---> *cannot find name userService*

const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: 'welcome',
      component: WelcomeComponent,
   },
   {
    path: 'product-selection',
    component: ProductSelectionComponent,
    canActivate: [ClientRoutesGuard],
    data: {
      isStepAccessible: steps.['welcome'].status,   //will return true or false
    },
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ClientRoutingModule {
   constructor(public userService: UserService) {}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add any such logic into other angular artifacts, like services, guards, resolvers, etc. The router module should only contain information about routing, not business logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to go to the `'product-selection'` route only when `steps['welcome'].status` is true, you should create a guard for it. For example:

```js
export class ProductSelectionGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.userService.user.steps['welcome'].status;
    }
}
```

Then include your guard in the `canActivate` array for your route:

```js
  // ... other routes
  {
    path: 'product-selection',
    component: ProductSelectionComponent,
    canActivate: [ClientRoutesGuard, ProductSelectionGuard],
    // data: {
    //  isStepAccessible: steps.['welcome'].status,   //will return true or false
    // },
  },
```